# Serving static files from Nginx proxy for ASP.NET Core SPA apps

Tags: performance, nginx, single-page-application, static-files, asp.net-core-2.2

As many know, it is recommended to use a proxy server for web apps served by an application server.

Also, it is recommended to use the proxy to serve static files.

For "normal" .NET Core apps the setup is simple. For example:

```
location /css/ {                        
    root /var/www/my.app.com/wwwroot;        
}   

location /js/ {                        
    root /var/www/my.app.com/wwwroot;        
}   

location /lib/ {                        
    root /var/www/my.app.com/wwwroot;        
}
```

But for .NET Core SPA apps (with Angular) wwwroot folder doesn't contain much and most of the content is stored in ClientApp.

Does it mean that for .NET Core SPA apps we have to sacrifice the static file serving feature for all that "SPA goodness" or are there some kinds of static files that still can be served by Nginx?